# How can I find out what ml2 extension drivers are enabled?

Tags: networking, dns, openstack

According to [this document on *"The Networking service internal DNS resolution"*](https://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/networking-guide/config-dns-int.html), a feature I need requires the `dns` extension driver in OpenStack,

```
[ml2]
extension_drivers = port_security,dns
```

How can I find what extension drivers my OpenStack's ml2 has?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to test this in my lab.

- Deployed with kolla ansible.
- Currently running Ussuri

If I add the `dns` driver to the ml2 config, I am now able to resolve network ports DNS through the `dnsmasq` inside my private network.

```
(venv) laurentdumont@openstack-deployer:/etc/kolla$ openstack port show 046068ee-4b1a-47b5-bfdb-91af916de1ee -c dns_assignment
+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field          | Value                                                                                    |
+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dns_assignment | fqdn='test-dns.os.coldnorthadmin.com.', hostname='test-dns', ip_address='10.100.100.112' |
+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In this case, the VM has one port and the port takes the name of the VM.

```
# nslookup -type=A test-dns.os.coldnorthadmin.com 10.100.100.2
Server:     10.100.100.2
Address:    10.100.100.2:53

Name:   test-dns.os.coldnorthadmin.com
Address: 10.100.100.112
```